# JQuery Buttons and Sliders not working when created in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can anyone provide insight into why the slider amounts aren't updating and the button icons do not change when created through a loop? If I go through and create each slider and variable named outside of a look it works fine. Not sure why it is not working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {

    var locked = [];
    var slider = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $( "#slider" + i ).slider({
              range: "max",
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              step: 0.01,
              value: 20,
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" + i ).val( ui.value );
              }
            });
            $( "#amount" + i ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
            $( "#amount" + i ).val(20.00);

            locked[i] = false;

            $("#Lock" + i).button({ 
                icons: {primary:'ui-icon-locked'},
                text: false 
                    }).click(function( event ) {

                        if(locked[i] == false){
                            $(this).button("option", { 
                                icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-unlocked'  }
                            });

                            locked[i] = true;

                        } else if(locked[i] == true){ 
                            $(this).button("option", { 
                                icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-locked'  }
                            });

                            locked[i] = false;
                        }
                    });
    }
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table border='0' style="width:500px;">
        <tr><td style="width:75px;">Var 1</td><td style="width:350px;"><div id="slider0"></div></td><td style="width:30px;"><input type="text" id="amount0" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"></td><td><button id='Lock0'></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="width:75px;">Var 2</td><td style="width:350px;"><div id="slider1"></div></td><td style="width:30px;"><input type="text" id="amount1" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"></td><td><button id='Lock1'></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="width:75px;">Var 3</td><td style="width:350px;"><div id="slider2"></div></td><td style="width:30px;"><input type="text" id="amount2" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"></td><td><button id='Lock2'></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="width:75px;">Var 4</td><td style="width:350px;"><div id="slider3"></div></td><td style="width:30px;"><input type="text" id="amount3" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"></td><td><button id='Lock3'></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="width:75px;">Var 5</td><td style="width:350px;"><div id="slider4"></div></td><td style="width:30px;"><input type="text" id="amount4" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;"></td><td><button id='Lock4'></td></tr>
    </table>



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Very likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/54q5u27h/

Comment: Thanks Sushil, that did it!!

Comment: great. let me post this as a solution. please upvote it and mark it as an answer.

Comment: @K.Ovitt i've posted my solution. please mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is give your `slider` div's a `data-id` attribute which you can use in the `slide` event to update the `input` values.

you can do the same for the `buttons`.

here's the html

```
<table border='0' style="width:500px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:75px;">Var 1</td>
        <td style="width:350px;">
            <div id="slider0" data-id='0'></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30px;">
            <input type="text" id="amount0" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id='Lock0' data-buttonid='0'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:75px;">Var 2</td>
        <td style="width:350px;">
            <div id="slider1" data-id='1'></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30px;">
            <input type="text" id="amount1" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id='Lock1' data-buttonid='1'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:75px;">Var 3</td>
        <td style="width:350px;">
            <div id="slider2" data-id='2'></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30px;">
            <input type="text" id="amount2" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id='Lock2' data-buttonid='2'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:75px;">Var 4</td>
        <td style="width:350px;">
            <div id="slider3" data-id='3'></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30px;">
            <input type="text" id="amount3" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id='Lock3' data-buttonid='3'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:75px;">Var 5</td>
        <td style="width:350px;">
            <div id="slider4" data-id='4'></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30px;">
            <input type="text" id="amount4" readonly value='20.00' style="width:40px;border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id='Lock4' data-buttonid='4'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

notice the `data-id` and the `data-buttonid` attributes

then just update your js to read the data attribute and update your input values

here's the JS

```
$(function() {

    var locked = [];
    var slider = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $("#slider" + i).slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            step: 0.01,
            value: 20,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                var id = $(this).data('id');

                $("#amount" + id).val(ui.value);

            }
        });
        $("#amount" + i).val($("#slider-range-max").slider("value"));
        $("#amount" + i).val(20.00);

        locked[i] = false;

        $("#Lock" + i).button({
            icons: {
                primary: 'ui-icon-locked'
            },
            text: false
        }).click(function(event) {
            var id = $(this).data('buttonid');

            console.log($(this));
            if (locked[id] == false) {
                $(this).button("option", {
                    icons: {
                        primary: 'ui-icon-unlocked'
                    }
                });

                locked[id] = true;

            } else if (locked[id] == true) {
                $(this).button("option", {
                    icons: {
                        primary: 'ui-icon-locked'
                    }
                });

                locked[id] = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

you can check this working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/54q5u27h/)**. hope this helps.